# Как сделать генератор слов с авто-заполнением

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ребята подскажите как мне написать код или можете пожалуйста предложить свой вариант кода.

В общем, что мне надо сделать. Моя задумка заключается в чём, в том, что мне надо реализовать код действия, чтобы можно было заполнить массив кода (массив с типом string) и данный массив со словами раскидать по рандомным полям, то есть по вертикали, по горизонтали, вверх, вниз, влево, вправо и.т.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] пример как показано на картинке. Буду очень признателен, если вы мне поможете !

Comment: Вот ссылка на проект, там все есть скрипты: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uFKZWde2MbAXzsLE9nXt7HoMa4ukottd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Вам нужен ИМЕННО код или алгоритм. Алгоритм в том, что сначала запихиваете на поле любые символы, а потом запихиваете нужные слова. Берете слово, берете рандомную клетку, выбираете направление. Направления, это, например (1,0)-вправо, (-1,0)-влево, (0,1) -вверх, (1,-1)- вправо-вниз и так далее. И в цикле (с количеством итераций равным длине слова) записываете буквы в яйейки. Советую также добавить проверку, чтобы не получилось так, что слово, например, в крайней правой ячейке и должно писаться еще правее.  Другой вариант: сначала записать все слова, а уже потом в пустые ячейки - рандомные букв

Comment: Максим именно код, можешь скачать проект и посмотреть там. То есть, что мне нужно. Надо создать поле, где можно было вписывать слова на пример: помидор и чай. И далее надо, чтобы данные слова находились рядом друг с другу. + надо чтобы они разбрасывались в рандомном порядке к примеру: слово "чай" располагался по вертикале, а слово "помидор" располагался под 45 градусов ну я думаю, что ты понял, что я имею ввиду..))) Просто я поставил перед собой цель сделать данную конструкцию и не могу данную задачу решить(( Буду очень признателен, если вы поможете мне !

Comment: То есть они могут еще и пересекаться? Просто если не могут, то попроще, а если могут, то, похоже, я все же не смогу помочь. Кстати, если вы обращаетесь к участнику, в данном случае ко мне, то пишите полное имя с собакой: @МаксимФисман. Так я получу уведомление о вашем сообщении

Comment: @МаксимФисман, да хорошо. Ну давайте сделаем, чтобы они не пересекались, а потом я попробую поковыряться в коде и что-то подобное сделать. Буду очень признатеден, если поможете с кодом :)

Comment: научись нормально ставить вопрос, потому что это читать невозможно

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас есть двумерный массив Array типа char размером Columns*Rows, и массив строк wordsAr со словами, которые будут записаны. Код будет выглядеть примерно так: Вот такой код я могу написать:

```
int[,] dir = int[,] {{0,1}{0,-1}{1,0}{-1,0}{1,1}{1,-1}{-1,1}{-1,-1}}; // Направления строк

for (int i = 0; i < wordsAr.Length; i++) { // Перебираем строки
    // Координаты ячейки, в которой начнется слово
    int cellX = Random.Range(0, Rows), cellY = Random.Range(0, Columns); 
    do {
        // Выбираем направление
        int tmpDir = dir[Random.Range(0, dir.Length)];
    while(isCellAcceptale(tmpDir) == false);
    // Пишем слово
    for (int j = 0; j < wordsAr[i].Length; j++) {
        Array[cellX][cellY] = wordsAr[i].charAt(j);
        cellX += tmpDir[0];
        cellY += tmpDir[1];
    }
} 

bool isCellAcceptable (int cellX, int cellY, string word, int[] direction) {
    int wordLength = word.Length;
    if (direction[0] == 1 && Columns - cellX > wordLength-1 ||  
        direction[0] == -1 && cellX > wordLength ||
        direction[1] == 1 && cellY > wordLength ||
        direction[1] == -1 && Rows - cellY > wordLength-1)
            return false;
    else return true;
```

Код писал без компиляции, так что могут быть ошибки и очепятки. Единственная возможная ошибка - если слово будет длинное и его невзможно будет написать из начальной строчки ни в одном направлении

Comment: спасибо, что помогаете, но у меня всё равно проблемма. Вот скрин https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rrfb28Fdd_idn2pnMSySHcC5O0Iu2CRF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Между 25и26 строкой добавьте: 'int[] tmpDir = dir[Random.Range(0, dir.Length)];

Comment: всё равно выдаёт ошибки. Вот скриншот:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tGtms2iTQPKxqYzkIfWGdgKNynRZTNvt/view?usp=sharing

Может давай свяжемся по вк ? Чтобы было удобнее vk.com/koresh_m
Спасибо